# REACT.js - sending prop state value as prop to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have such code in React.js:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      clicks: 0
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (<div>
       <button onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>Click it</button>


      <Btn name={this.state.clicks}/>
      <Btn name="sssssss"/>
      <Btn name="aaaaaaa"/>

    </div>)
  }

    increment() {
    this.setState({
      clicks: this.state.clicks + 1
    })
  }


}

class Btn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      prop: "xyz"
    };
  }


  render () {
  return ( <div className="button">{props.name}</div>)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

What is going on here?
I have two components - App and Btn which is Parent and Child. In App there is also button with word "Click it". When i click it the state "clicks" property is incremented. App has 3 Btn components which are called with prop called name. 
What i want to achieve is:
- grab prop name and use it in child component
- also have it dynamically changable

What do I do wrong?

Comment: all i needed to do was put this.props.name instead of props.name - problem solved

Comment: Use props.name when you deal with stateless components, and this.props.name when it's a class components like Btn